# how to fix the error "Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-19/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"?

Tags: java, javafx

code was working fine but now when i try to run it all i get is the error
**Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-19/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**
this is driving me insane how do i fix this?????

```
> Task :Main.main() FAILED
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module mysql.connector.j not found, required by system.test.librarysystem
```

**main class**

```
package system.test.librarysystem;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml")));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Library system") ;
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args); }

}
```

EDIT:
here are the module-info and my gradle.build file

**module-info**

```
module system.test.librarysystem {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.sql;
    requires mysql.connector.j;


    opens system.test.librarysystem to javafx.fxml;
    exports system.test.librarysystem;
}
```

**gradle.build**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'system.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = '19'
targetCompatibility = '19'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'system.test.librarysystem'
    mainClass = 'system.test.librarysystem.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '19'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.32'
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

Comment: Do you need that module? The code you posted obviously does not use it.

Comment: The fxml page it calls does use it so yeah i need that module

Comment: Post your `module-info.java` and your build configuration (`pom.xml` for Maven or `build.gradle` for Gradle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that i had **requires mysql.connector.j;** in my module-info file and this was causing the error, removing it resolved the error

Answer (score 0):

1. Hi there, based on your given source code it's difficult to get the solution. Try to include other source files which are in `librarysystem package`
2. Based on your error message, particularly this line:

   ```
   java.lang.module.FindException: Module mysql.connector.j not found, 
   required by system.test.librarysystem
   ```

   there could be several reasons, `mysql.connector.j` may not be installed in your system. Check whether it is installed properly
3. Another reason might be `module path` which is not properly configured. You can check the module path by following command on terminal:

   ```
   java --list-modules
   ```